# Spring Boot MVC html file paths not working

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

Just started working with Spring Boot MVC. Been scratching my head trying to organize my folders.

I have my index.html, CSS, and image files in following folders:

- `/resources/static`,
- `/resources/static/css` and
- `/resources/static/images` respectively.

Everything works fine. I have an HTML file in `/resources/templates/greeting.html` and it is correctly accessed by my controller class. However, I created some subfolders, `/resources/templates/management/*.html` but my `/resource/templates/greeting.html` cannot href the folders and I get a 404 error.

If I take the files out of `/management` and put them in `/resources` they are accessed fine. Here is my `index.html` code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head> 
    <title>AVI Administrator</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="\css\indexstyles.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="pagewrap">

    <div class="header">
        <img src="\images\avi.png" alt="AVI" style="width:90px;height:50px;" >
        <h1> Edge Administrative Dashboard </h1>
    </div>

    <section id="content">
        <center>
            <img src="\images\wrench_1024.png" alt="Administration" style="width:200px;height:200px;" >
            <h2>Account Management</h2>
        </center>
        <br>
        <a href="\management\addadministrator.html" style="text-decoration: none" >&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp; Add/Edit System Administrator Account<p/></a>
        <a href="\management\addclient.html" style="text-decoration: none" >&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp; Add/Edit Tenant Client Account<p/></a>
        <a href="\management\addtenant.html" style="text-decoration: none" >&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp; Add/Edit Tenant Account<p/></a>
        <a href="\management\addtenantedgedevice.html" style="text-decoration: none" >&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp; Add/Edit Edge Device<p/></a>
        <a href="\management\addtenantsubscription.html" style="text-decoration: none" >&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp; Add/Edit Tenant Subscription<p/></a>
    </section>

    <footer>

    </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone have an idea what is going on? I am creating an executable JAR and have read about some of the file limitations of WEB-INF.  Does Spring Boot required all HTML files to be in `/resources` folder?

I don't seem to be violating the spring-boot MVC jar issues. Is there a better way of organizing the folders to keep the files a little better organized? Recommendations are welcome.

Comment: Maybe you get 404 error because of `/resources/template/management/*.html` instead of `/resources/templates/management/*.html`? Just typo in `template(s)`. Having subfolders is ok, you can manage it in your controllers `return "subfolder/pageName";`

Comment: Sorry about the typo's.  They were my mistakes when I typed into stackoverflow.  The actual source is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after a lot of reading I finally found out the problem.  The first thing that caused a lot of problems was the use of Spring Boot MVC and creating an executable Jar.  When you create a "Spring Boot Starter Project" 2 paths are created,

```
resources
   |
   --> static
   |
   --> templates
```

By default, when using an executable jar all static content -- css, js, fonts -- is placed in the static folder.  If an index.html is used it also is placed in the static file.  Again, by default, all other html files are placed in the template folder.  By following these default standards it works fine.  An issue that really caused me to waste a lot of effort was creating an executable .jar and using the typical MVC file structure webapp --> WEB-INF.  An executable jar ignores the webapp file structure.  Another little surprise is that .jsp's really don't work well with Spring Boot MVC when an executable .jar is created.  Almost all of these problems are eliminated with a WAR deployment.  Spring Boot recommends thymeleaf or html for the view pages when using executable .jars.

Any other things I might if missed?

Comment: I think you're getting closer. Spring Boot supports various templating engines (Freemarker, thymeleaf, Mustache, Groovy), .jsp's will work fine if you are deploying as .war to a standard web container. What I also noticed from your code is that you're referencing the html files statically. The hrefs should point to controller request mappings. It is the controllers that should be calling the your views/html files (MVC).

Comment: Olantobi...Thanks for pointing out the static hrefs.  I fixed the hrefs and are pointing to the controller request mappings instead of .jsp.  I have the spring boot mvc working fine.  The final problem was with the executable jars.  I just created an executable .war in the gradle build and everything worked fine.  You execute the .war in the command line as; java -jar myjarname.war

Answer (score 0):

Your reference is wrong.

Change it to:

```
<a href="management/addadministrator.html" style="text-decoration: none" >&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp; Add/Edit System Administrator Account<p/></a>
<a href="management/addclient.html" style="text-decoration: none" >&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp; Add/Edit Tenant Client Account<p/></a>
```

Comment: Tried it but did not work.  I also tried <a href="resources/templates/management/addadministrator.html" style=...</a> and

Comment: Just to re-iterate, I am using spring-boot MVC.  The file organization is a little different from most web applications.  My current file organization that does not work is /resources/templates/management/addclient.html.  I moved the management folder into the static folder and it worked.  The working organization is /resources/static/management/addclient.html.  I guess spring-boot MVC wants static content in the static file and controller referenced files in the template folder.  Does this make sense?  Any other opinions?